# Check if a user has voted for the maximum number of items he can vote for

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table `items`

```
id  maxVotes    parent      type
10  2           9           heading 
11  0           10          item
12  0           10          item
```

Table `votes`

```
userId  votedFor parent
1       11       10 
1       12       10
2       12       10
```

I'm trying to check if an item exists, and if a user has voted for the maximum number of items permitted under that heading.

In the example above, table `items` contains items. Table `votes` contains votes cast by the users.

Table `items` `type : heading` specifies the maximum number of items a user can vote for `col : maxVotes`. In this case, it's `2`.

In table `votes` `user 1` has voted on 2 items and can vote no more for `items` that are under that heading. User 2 can vote for 1 item more.

It goes on like that.

**The way I current do it (using php), is to:**

`select id, parent from items where id = 11 //The item exists.`

`select maxVotes from items where id = parent // This gives me the maximum items a user can vote for.`

`select count(votedFor) as votes from votes where userId = 1 // This'll give me 2.`

`User 1 can vote no more, but user 2 can vote once more -> Add his vote to the votes table`

Can you think of a easier, more efficient and sophisticated way to do this, other than the way I do it above?

I can make changes to things since this still isn't implemented. Or, is this the best way?

Comment: Norman You escaped after posting question? :)

Comment: I'm here. You can't tell someones replied until you check the site. The site does not send you emails for each answer immediately ;-)

Comment: You have posted 32 secs before from now. I replied you soon. But you replied after 40 mins. Don't blame this website. If any answer or comment posted mean. In your inbox(stackoverflow inbox) you will get notification. Dont you know that?

Comment: I am not ready to fight with you. If my answer helps you, follow that or just leave it.

Comment: Take it easy man. You still need to check the site to find out if someones replied, remember that. I was using MS Word. How will I ever know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is okay as it is, you can combine all steps in one query.

```
SELECT 
userId
FROM votes
# WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM votes sv WHERE sv.userId = votes.userId
#                   AND votedFor = 11)
GROUP BY userId
HAVING COUNT(*) < (
  SELECT
  MAX(i2.maxVotes)
  FROM
  items i1
  INNER JOIN items i2 ON i1.parent = i2.id
  WHERE
  i1.id = 11 /*Here you choose which item*/
)
```

This query will give you users that can still vote. Uncomment the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` part to exclude users who haven't reached vote limit but have voted for the item you are checking.

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fb6f/2/0).

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN numberOfVotes >= maxVotesForItem THEN 'Has reached vote limit'
     ELSE CONCAT('User has ', maxVotesForItem - numberOfVotes, ' vote left')
END AS result
/*optionally include...*/
#, numberOfVotes, maxVotesForItem
FROM (
  SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS numberOfVotes
  , (SELECT
     MAX(i2.maxVotes)
     FROM
     items i1
     INNER JOIN items i2 ON i1.parent = i2.id
     WHERE
     i1.id = 11 /*Here you choose which item*/
  ) AS maxVotesForItem
  FROM
  votes
  WHERE 
  userId = 2 /*Here you choose which user*/
) sq
```

Again an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fb6f/7/1).

Comment: Actually, my objective is to check if `a particular` user (userId will be supplied by me) has reached the maximum number of items he can vote for under that heading, or if he has not reach that count. In this case, the maximum number of items he can vote for is 2. I need to check for the supplied user eg: user 1 or user 2. That users id will come from a querystring.

Comment: So, check in `votes` if user 1 has voted for 2 items under parent 10.

Comment: @Norman Just add `WHERE userId = whateverID`? oO Am I not getting the question right?

Comment: Umm... your fiddle displays `all the users` who `can vote` i.e those who have not reached the max limit. I need to check if the supplied user id can vote or has reached max votes. Maybe I've not fully understood your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was fiddling with your fiddle, but you posted an update by then. I fiddle with this from here :)

Comment: Your web site is down :) Nice site name. Thought of getting in touch with you. Any way I can?

Comment: Why do you want to get in touch with me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30422/discussion-between-norman-and-tombom)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the table structure by adding one more field voteCount and store the voteFor in json structure as below,

```
Table: UserVote

userId  voteCount voteFor
1       2         {11,12}
2       1         {11}
```

So while voting you can insert the count in this table itself and check the vote count from here itself.

(OR)

Add one more table along with your 2 tables as voteCount for having counts only

```
Table: VoteCount

userId  voteCount
1       2        
2       1        


Table items

id  maxVotes    parent      type
10  2           9           heading 
11  0           10          item
12  0           10          item

Table votes

userId  votedFor
1       11
1       12
2       12
```

**First method is efficient one and it reduce one table. Easy to update also. Retrieve json data from DB decode it. Add one id to that array. Encode and Update it. Thats all.**

Comment: It depends on your maximum count. Because for voting you wont have allow more than 5 vote maxi. Or you have to create a voteCount as new table. and have your old table as it is. In new table you can have only userID and voteCount. Check the answer i have edited.

Comment: First method is easy and it reduce one table. Easy to update also. Retrieve json data from DB decode it. Add one id to that array. Encode and Update it. Thats all.